# Which software does Aptana Studio 3 use for its terminal in Windows 7

Tags: aptana, aptana3

The Windows Version of Aptana Studio 3 features a nice unix-bash-like terminal. I wonder with which software this has been achived. win-bash, cygwin or something else? It would be useful to know which bash-features you can rely on.

Comment: It's open-source. You can have a look in the source-tree/source-code and work it out. I reckon this page may have your answer: https://github.com/aptana/studio3/tree/development/native (Hint: something else)